# How to get "applymapping" to work properly when transforming datatypes

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

My issue is that a specific column in my ETL job is not converting into the sought after data type, this means that every time the job is run and later crawled (daily), the data type is "string" and should be "int"(integer).

In the datasource the data type is "bigint" and I want it to be either "bigint" or "int" in the final table.

However, this doesnt happen and the data type of the column "tester" end up being string.

This is a column used in many queries, therefore it is essential that it can be converted into integer (as it previously was prior to a change).

I have tried multiple combinations of source data type and target data type, however none seems to work and all end up being string.

I hope that you can help me as I am no expert to AWS, and do not have access to any further support.

Below my code of the ETL job is pasted (censored)

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('XX-bi-team')
bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="Tables_after_jobs/XX/tester/").delete()


## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "mysql_XX", table_name = "XX_XX_XX", transformation_ctx = "datasource0"]
## @return: datasource0
## @inputs: []
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "mysql_XX", table_name = "XX_XX_XX", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
## @type: ApplyMapping
## @args: [mapping = [("v1", "string", "v1", "string"), ("XX_threshold_XX", "string", "XX_threshold_XX", "string"), ("limit_XX", "string", "limit_XX", "string"), ("XX_threshold", "decimal(19,2)", "XX_threshold", "decimal(19,2)"), ("created", "timestamp", "created", "timestamp"), ("gee_XX", "string", "gee_XX", "string"), ("type", "string", "type", "string"), ("uuid", "binary", "uuid", "binary"), ("v2", "int", "v2", "int"), ("geeXX", "decimal(19,2)", "geeXX", "decimal(19,2)"), ("limitXX", "decimal(29,2)", "limitXX", "decimal(29,2)"), ("XX", "int", "XX", "int"), ("id", "long", "id", "long"), ("XX", "decimal(29,2)", "XX", "decimal(29,2)"), ("XX_XX_id", "long", "XX_XX_id", "long"), ("replaces_id", "long", "tester", "int")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1"]
## @return: applymapping1
## @inputs: [frame = datasource0]
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("v1", "string", "v1", "string"), ("XX_threshold_XX", "string", "XX_threshold_XX", "string"), ("limit_XX", "string", "limit_XX", "string"), ("XX_threshold", "decimal(19,2)", "XX_threshold", "decimal(19,2)"), ("created", "timestamp", "created", "timestamp"), ("gee_XX", "string", "gee_XX", "string"), ("type", "string", "type", "string"), ("uuid", "binary", "uuid", "binary"), ("v2", "int", "v2", "int"), ("geeXX", "decimal(19,2)", "geeXX", "decimal(19,2)"), ("limitXX", "decimal(29,2)", "limitXX", "decimal(29,2)"), ("XX", "int", "XX", "int"), ("id", "long", "id", "long"), ("XX", "decimal(29,2)", "XX", "decimal(29,2)"), ("XX_XX_id", "long", "XX_XX_id", "long"), ("tester", "bigint", "tester", "int")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
## @type: DataSink
## @args: [connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://XX-bi-team/Tables_after_jobs/XX/tester"}, format = "json", transformation_ctx = "datasink2"]
## @return: datasink2
## @inputs: [frame = applymapping1]
datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = applymapping1, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://XX-bi-team/Tables_after_jobs/XX/tester"}, format = "json", transformation_ctx = "datasink2")
job.commit()
```

As mentioned above, I need the column "tester" to become an integer and NOT a string, as it does in the current state.

I hope you help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to print schema of `datasource0` (`datasource0.printSchema( )`) first to see actual data type. If it's a choice type then you need to resolve it using [ResolveChoice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-ResolveChoice.html).

See also [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-samples-medicaid.html#aws-glue-programming-python-samples-medicaid-schemas).